# Registry location for cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I've been looking through the internet trying to find the location of the command prompt in the registry, as I want to see if there is a way to enlarge the text using the registry, and generally having a look through it's settings within the registry, however I can't find the location on the internet, or on my own looking through the registry, can anyone tell me the following:

1. Where is the command prompt in the registry?
2. Is there a way to edit a shortcut's properties within the command line?

Either of these may solve my quest to alter the text automatically, rather than have to set up the shortcut of a bat file every time I make one

Thanks!

Comment: This question is about system management. Maybe you have more change asking this on another site sucha as "Super User"

Comment: Batchers would customarily have a shortcut to invoke `cmd`. If you copy that shortcut, then change the colours/font/other characteristic using "properties" and compare the result with that copy, you should be able to establish what changes you need to make to the shortcut you want to alter.

Answer (score 0):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console
```

and

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
```

The Console key can have custom setting for different .exe files.